# How to turn NA rows into columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(AP = c("1.0", "1.0", "1.0", "2.2", "2.2", "3.1", "3.1", "3.1", "3.1", "3.1"),
                   PROFISSIONAL = c("JULIA", "JULIA", "JULIA", "ROSANA", "ROSANA", "JEFERSON", "JEFERSON", "JEFERSON", "JEFERSON", "JEFERSON"),
                   NOME = c("MARIA A", NA, NA, "RENATA", NA, "CLAUDIA", NA, NA, NA, NA),
                   MEDICAMENTO = c("LOSARTANA", "PARACETAMOL", "NEOSORO", "LOSARTANA", "ATENOLOL", "SINVASTATINA", "AAS", "ENALAPRIL", "HIDROCLOROTIAZIDA", "FLUOXETINA"))
```

Each NA under the "NOME" variable is the same person from the name above. For example, the 4 NAs after CLAUDIA belong to CLAUDIA. I need to turn these rows to columns for the specific name it belongs to.

[image]

This would be the desired output:

```
data2 <- data.frame(AP = c("1.0", "2.2", "3.1"),
                   PROFISSIONAL = c("JULIA", "ROSANA", "JEFERSON"),
                   NOME = c("MARIA A", "RENATA", "CLAUDIA"),
                   MEDICAMENTO1 = c("LOSARTANA", "LOSARTANA", "SINVASTATINA"),
                   MEDICAMENTO2 = c("PARACETAMOL", "ATENOLOL", "AAS"),
                   MEDICAMENTO3 = c("NEOSORO", NA, "ENALAPRIL"),
                   MEDICAMENTO4 = c(NA, NA,  "HIDROCLOROTIAZIDA"),
                   MEDICAMENTO5 = c(NA, NA,  "FLUOXETINA"))
```

[image]

Is there any way I can do that with all variables using the "NOME" as NA condition?

EDIT: Besides the MEDICAMENTO variable, there are also other variables: DIF, STATUS, STATUS2, INDICAÇÃO, STATUS9, DOSE1,    DOSE2, FREQ1, FREQ2, DOSEREAL1 and DOSEREAL2. The AP and PROFISSIONAL variables can be assigned to different names. For example, different NOME can be assigned to same PROFISSIONAL and AP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
data |>
  fill(NOME) |>
  mutate(col = paste0("MEDICAMENTO", row_number()), .by = AP) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = MEDICAMENTO)

# A tibble: 3 × 8
  AP    PROFISSIONAL NOME    MEDICAMENTO1 MEDICAMENTO2 MEDICAMENTO3 MEDICAMENTO4    MEDICAMENTO5
  <chr> <chr>        <chr>   <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>           <chr>       
1 1.0   JULIA        MARIA A LOSARTANA    PARACETAMOL  NEOSORO      NA              NA          
2 2.2   ROSANA       RENATA  LOSARTANA    ATENOLOL     NA           NA              NA          
3 3.1   JEFERSON     CLAUDIA SINVASTATINA AAS          ENALAPRIL    HIDROCLOROTIAZ… FLUOXETINA
```

Answer (score 2):

If your *NOME* data has multiple non-`NA` values select them using `purrr::map`

Note, using a slightly modified data set to reflect that

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ list(.x)), .by = c(AP, PROFISSIONAL)) %>% 
  mutate(NOME = purrr::map(NOME, ~ .x[!is.na(.x)])) %>% 
  unnest_wider(-c(AP, PROFISSIONAL), names_sep="")

# A tibble: 3 × 9
  AP    PROFISSIONAL NOME1   NOME2 MEDICAMENTO1 MEDICA…¹ MEDIC…² MEDIC…³ MEDIC…⁴
  <chr> <chr>        <chr>   <chr> <chr>        <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 1.0   JULIA        MARIA A JJ O  LOSARTANA    PARACET… NEOSORO NA      NA     
2 2.2   ROSANA       RENATA  NA    LOSARTANA    ATENOLOL NA      NA      NA     
3 3.1   JEFERSON     CLAUDIA GERO  SINVASTATINA AAS      ENALAP… HIDROC… FLUOXE…
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​MEDICAMENTO2, ²​MEDICAMENTO3,
#   ³​MEDICAMENTO4, ⁴​MEDICAMENTO5
```

##### Data

```
data <- structure(list(AP = c("1.0", "1.0", "1.0", "2.2", "2.2", "3.1", 
"3.1", "3.1", "3.1", "3.1"), PROFISSIONAL = c("JULIA", "JULIA", 
"JULIA", "ROSANA", "ROSANA", "JEFERSON", "JEFERSON", "JEFERSON", 
"JEFERSON", "JEFERSON"), NOME = c("MARIA A", "JJ O", NA, "RENATA", 
NA, "CLAUDIA", NA, "GERO", NA, NA), MEDICAMENTO = c("LOSARTANA", 
"PARACETAMOL", "NEOSORO", "LOSARTANA", "ATENOLOL", "SINVASTATINA", 
"AAS", "ENALAPRIL", "HIDROCLOROTIAZIDA", "FLUOXETINA")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the lousy code.
Does this work? I called it `data`

```
map_df(unique(data$PROFISSIONAL),~
      data |>
      filter(PROFISSIONAL==.) |>
      mutate(med = paste0("medicamentio",1:length(unique(MEDICAMENTO)))) |> 
      pivot_wider(id_cols = AP,
                  values_from = MEDICAMENTO,
                  names_from = med)
      
      
      ) |> 
  mutate(NOME = unique(data$NOME[complete.cases(data$NOME)]),.after=AP)
```

Output:

```
A tibble: 3 x 7
  AP    NOME    medicamentio1 medicamentio2 medicamentio3 medicamentio4     medicamentio5
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>             <chr>        
1 1.0   MARIA A LOSARTANA     PARACETAMOL   NEOSORO       NA                NA           
2 2.2   RENATA  LOSARTANA     ATENOLOL      NA            NA                NA           
3 3.1   CLAUDIA SINVASTATINA  AAS           ENALAPRIL     HIDROCLOROTIAZIDA FLUOXETINA
```

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly with the reproductible data, but I can't seem to apply it to my real data. Besides the MEDICAMENTO variable, there are other variables that should be "Horizontalized" as well like INDICACAO, STATUS9, DOSE1, DOSE2, FREQ1, FREQ2.. The AP and PROFISSIONAL variables also apply to other NAME, so I can have the same AP and same PROFISSIONAL to diferrent NAMES. Anyways, thanks for your help.